# Nginx and Unicorn Set up Not sure what I am doing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

This is my first time setting up nginx and unicorn, someone directed me to this tutorial:

http://teohm.github.io/blog/2013/04/17/chef-cookbooks-for-busy-ruby-developers/

I have a general understanding of what I am doing but I am stuck on this section:

Install chef-solo on remote server

when I run 
    `bundle exec knife solo prepare testbox`

I get

```
ERROR: Network Error: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Check your knife configuration and network settings
```

I am guessing that I don't have  ~/.ssh/config

this is from the example

```
Host testbox
  User ubuntu
  Hostname ec2-51-221-13-121.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/testbox_ec2.pem
```

am I suppose to make a config file in .ssh? should I switch to ubuntu?

I am using heroku, how should I find my hostname? what is the pem file in ssh?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used knife...  It might be worth checking out this [this blog post](http://ariejan.net/2011/09/14/lighting-fast-zero-downtime-deployments-with-git-capistrano-nginx-and-unicorn/) about setting up Capistrano, Nginx, and Unicorn - I've always found Capistrano to be a good deployment app (and there's lots of support for it, especially on SO).

On Heroku, you don't deploy as you would with Capistrano or any other deployment utility - you simply push to a branch on your Heroku server.  See:  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git for how to deploy on Heroku using Git.